# Why is table creation failing for an in-memory sqlite database?

Tags: python, sqlite, twisted, in-memory-database

I am trying to create an in-memory sqlite database using `twisted.enterprise.adbapi.ConnectionPool`.

## Problem Description:

The following code works as expected:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
from twisted.internet.task import react
from twisted.internet import defer
from twisted.enterprise.adbapi import ConnectionPool

sql_init = """
    CREATE TABLE ajxp_changes ( seq INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, node_id NUMERIC, type TEXT, source TEXT, target TEXT, deleted_md5 TEXT );
    CREATE TABLE ajxp_index ( node_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, node_path TEXT, bytesize NUMERIC, md5 TEXT, mtime NUMERIC, stat_result BLOB);

    CREATE TRIGGER LOG_INSERT AFTER INSERT ON ajxp_index BEGIN INSERT INTO ajxp_changes (node_id,source,target,type) VALUES (new.node_id, "NULL", new.node_path, "create"); END;
    """

sql_insert = "INSERT INTO ajxp_index (node_path,bytesize,md5,mtime,stat_result) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);"

sql_file_path = "/tmp/test.sqlite"

@react
@defer.inlineCallbacks
def main(reactor):
    cp = ConnectionPool("sqlite3", sql_file_path, check_same_thread=False)
    yield cp.runInteraction(lambda c, s: c.executescript(s), sql_init)

    params = (
        "/tmp/test.txt",
        "64",
        "5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592",
        2832345,
        "xxxxxx"
    )
    yield cp.runOperation(sql_insert, params)
```

However, replacing `sql_file_path="/tmp/test.sqlite` with `sql_file_path=":memory:"` suddenly causes the script to fail with the following traceback:

```
$ python test.py 
main function encountered error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 500, in errback
    self._startRunCallbacks(fail)
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 567, in _startRunCallbacks
    self._runCallbacks()
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1357, in gotResult
    _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)
--- <exception caught here> ---
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1299, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "test.py", line 35, in main
    yield cp.runOperation(sql_insert, params)
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 250, in inContext
    result = inContext.theWork()
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 266, in <lambda>
    inContext.theWork = lambda: context.call(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 122, in callWithContext
    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 85, in callWithContext
    return func(*args,**kw)
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/enterprise/adbapi.py", line 477, in _runInteraction
    compat.reraise(excValue, excTraceback)
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/python/compat.py", line 467, in reraise
    raise exception.with_traceback(traceback)
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/enterprise/adbapi.py", line 467, in _runInteraction
    result = interaction(trans, *args, **kw)
  File "/Users/lthibault/.pyenv/versions/3.5.3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/twisted/enterprise/adbapi.py", line 486, in _runOperation
    trans.execute(*args, **kw)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: ajxp_index
```

## What I have tried

### 1. Replicate in standard library

I first sought to determine whether the problem related to sqlite, or to twisted.  To do so, I ran the following script, **which behaves as expected**.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")
conn.executescript(sql_init)
conn.execute(
    sql_insert,
    ("/tmp/test.txt", "64", "5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592", 2832345, "xxxxxx"),
)
```

**Conclusion:**  The issue stems from `twisted.enterprise.adbapi.ConnectionPool`

### 2.  Try using different `ConnectionPool` methods to run the `INSERT` statement.

Admittedly, I was grasping at straws at this point, but I figured the issue might stem from my use of `runOperation`.  I decided to replicate the original example using `runInteraction` and `runQuery`.

The following replacements for `yield cp.runOperation(sql_insert, params)` **also fail with an identical error**.

- `yield cp.runInteraction(lambda c, s, p: c.execute(s), sql_insert, params)`
- `yield cp.runQuery(sql_insert, params)`

Importantly, changing the sqlite database path from `:memory:` to some path on persistent storage, both `runInteraction` and `runQuery` work as expected.

**Conclusion:**  the problem has to do with using an in-memory sqlite database inside of Twisted.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you `COMMIT`?

Comment: @KlausD. No, I'm not issuing any `COMMIT`s.  My understanding is that the `sqlite3` module implicitly runs transactions.  Did you have anything specific in mind I could try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it turns out that under the hood, `ConnectionPool` is trying to connect to `:memory:` each time a query method is called, thus re-creating the database every time.

The solution seems to be to write a [DB-API v.20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) module that wraps sqlite3 and always hands back the same `:memory:` connection when its connect function is called.